# Closed form for $\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} (j - i)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, closed-form, products

Is there a closed form for $\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} (j - i)$? It looks like something like a determinant of a Vandermonde matrix, but I can't seem to get it to fit.

Comment: I'm lazy to do this. Try to evaluate this expression for few values of $k$ say $k = 1,2,\ldots,10$. May be we can see a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the square of this quantity is the discriminant of the polynomial whose roots are the integers from 1 to $k$, so your observation that this is the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix is correct.
None of the below are close forms, but here are two alternative formulas that may (or may not) be helpful: $$\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq k}(j-i)=\prod_{n=1}^{k-1} n!=\prod_{n=1}^{k-1}n^{k-n}$$

Comment: Apparently there is not closed form for $\prod_{n=1}^{k-1} n!$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialProducts.html

Comment: @J.D. So you say it's wrong (from there on)?

Comment: @draks No no! Indeed $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{k-1} n!=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{k-1}n^{k-n}$. I'm just answering OP's question whether a closed form exists.

Comment: It uses the [Barnes G function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=prod+n%21+from+n%3D1+to+r) for the closed form

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a closed form, but you will find many references at http://oeis.org/A000178.